# Extracting raster pixels in qGIS

Tags: raster, qgis

I have a raster file with two bands and a vector shapefile. I used raster extraction by mask and created the desired area. Now I want to calculate the number of pixels for Band 1 and Band 2 of the new clipped mask file. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: this is not a coding question. You might have more luck on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can simply get the size of your raster (the number of pixels) by multiplying the height and width of the raster, which can be found under "Properties" > "Information".